# Nicer way to write this .map() in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, code-cleanup

I have an array that looks like this: `[[3, 1], 4, [3, 3, 4], 4, :sync, 1, 2]`

I want to map through the array, and...

- If the item is an integer, replace it with something else
- If the item is an array, replace only the index 0 item, and return the array

This is what I have so far but it's very ugly. Is there a better way to write this?

Maybe I can somehow use `#tap`?

```
work.map! do |w|
  if w.is_a? Array
    w[0] = console.button_map[w[0]] || w[0]
    w
  else
    console.button_map[w] || w
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably more appropriate for the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on this, not sure if it can be cleaner:

```
work.map! do |w|                                        
  if w.is_a? Array                                      
    w.tap{|x| x[0] = console.button_map[x[0]] || x[0] } 
  else                                                  
    console.button_map[w] || w                          
  end                                                   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Array()` to normalize the input and then there is only on case left:

```
work.map! do |w|
  element = Array(w).first
  console.button_map[element] || element
end
```

Comment: Or even two separate maps: `a.map { |e| Array(e).first }.map { |e| console.button_map[e] || e }`.

Comment: I don't follow. I understand `element = Array(work).first` (which I believe you could also write `element = [*work].first`), but if (the argument) `work` is an array, aren't you mapping it to some function of it's first element, rather than keeping the rest of it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: [`Array(w)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) transforms the input into an array unless it is already an array: `Array(nil) #=> []`, `Array(:foo) #=> [:foo]`, but `Array([:foo]) #=> [:foo]`

Comment: Nice! That's an amazing idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
work = [[3, 1], 4, [3, 3, 4], 4, :sync, 1, 2, [5]]

work.map! do |w|
  val = my_method [*w].first
  case w
  when Array then [val, *w[1..-1]]
  else val
  end
end

def my_method(n)
  case n
  when Fixnum then n+4
  else n.to_s
  end
end

work
  #=> [[7, 1], 8, [7, 3, 4], 8, "sync", 5, 6, [9]]
```

Note:

```
[*[1,2]] #=> [1,2]
[*3]     #=> [3]
```